# "-std=gnu++0x"option for MacOS

Tags: c++, xcode, gcc, c++11, osx-lion

I'm trying to compile a CMake project which uses

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} "-Wall -std=gnu++0x")
```

in the CMakeLists.txt file under MacOS X Lion. I have installed XCode 4.2.1. but the compiler fails with this:

```
cd something/src/lib && /usr/bin/c++   -Dlib_ginacra_EXPORTS -Wall -std=gnu++0x -fPIC   -o CMakeFiles/lib_ginacra.dir/utilities.cpp.o -c something/src/lib/utilities.cpp
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=gnu++0x"
```

The compiler's verion is:

```
c++ --version
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.1.00)
```

Comment: You'll need a newer version of GCC. (http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html)

Comment: Thanks! What be the preferred (elegant) way to do that with MacOS X Lion?

Comment: Did you try `clang`?  Try `export CC=clang` and `export CXX=clang++` before running `cmake`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GCC 4.2 is ancient, but Apple don't ship a newer version.

You can either install a modern GCC from somewhere like Mac Ports (which is probably simpler and quicker) or build it yourself following the instructions at http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC

Comment: The latest Xcode doesn't come with any newer version of gcc. I think it's still llvm-gcc-4.2.

Comment: `brew tap homebrew/versions && brew install gcc48`

Answer (score 0):

For Lion users facing this issue:

Download and Install the **MacPorts-2.2.1-10.7-Lion.pkg** MacPorts
    installer package from [here](https://distfiles.macports.org/MacPorts/)

in a terminal, search for newer GCC versions:

```
$  port search --name --glob 'gcc*'
```

install a newer version (I went with gcc5)

```
$  sudo port install gcc5
```

get the name of your new version, and set it as default

```
$ port select --list gcc

Available versions for gcc:
    llvm-gcc42
    mp-gcc5
    none (active)

$ sudo port select --set gcc mp-gcc5
```

open a new terminal and validate you're updated:

```
$ c++ --version
c++ (MacPorts gcc5 5.2.0_0) 5.2.0
```

Answer (score -1):

Most of you getting that error **"cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option -std=gnu++0x"** while installing nodejs extension which requires C++ compilation with **node-gyp**.
So how to solve this error so here is the solution. Basically you get these errors because of Nodejs different version as many node libraries requires C or C++ compilation while installing. So Nodejs older version uses **python 2.7** with **gcc** compiler less than version 4.2 but Nodejs newer version uses **gcc44** compiler that's why you get above error while installing any nodejs library.

So you need to degrade your nodejs and node-gyp version and specify the python version if you have multiple python versions installed on your system and then you will not get above error anymore.

[Click here to see full tutorial](http://webbio.nl/wikiweb/nodejs-node-gyp-build-error-while-installing-extension-cc1plus-error-unrecognized-command-line-option-stdgnu0x/)