# How to use #include <random> with g++ on a Mac?

Tags: c++, include, g++

I'm trying to compile a c++ program that I got from someone else. It's been developed on windows and g++ is giving some compile errors. One of them is with

```
#include <random>
```

Which gives the following error: `CandidateSolution.cpp:2:18: error: random: No such file or directory`. I tried to find where I can get the error.h file from but I can't find it. How can I get this to work?

Comment: Note that the error from your compiler is telling you that there's was an error finding the header file named `random`, not that it's looking for a file called `error.h` ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That header is new to C++11. Try using `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++0x`. Also, make sure your compiler is up to date.

Comment: Should I put this in the code? I tried it on the commandline `Niek$ g++ *.cpp -std=c++0x` but that doesn't work.

Comment: Doesn't work because it complains about the -std=c++0x or still the header? As you guessed, the -std=c++0x should go on the command line.

Comment: I get the following `cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++0x"`

Comment: Try -std=c++11, if both don't work you need to update your g++ version. (Also it would help to know your gcc version, run `g++ -v` for this information.

Comment: Using c++11 gives the same error. The version I'm using is `gcc version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)`

Comment: It turns out apparently this is a problem with macs using an ancient version of gcc. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480654/std-gnu0xoption-for-macos. 4.2.1 is old enough that it doesn't have any C++11 support at all.