# Basic C++ Pseudo-Random Number Generation

Tags: c++, c++11

I am learning C++ and something I would like to do is be able to generate pseudo-random numbers. I am aware that you can `#include <random>` however it seems as if that is still unstable (I could not get it to work.) Any help on the matter is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Show us how you *tried* to get it to work, and perhaps see some of the examples [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random)

Comment: My compiler does not support the random header. rand() is good enough for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772533/how-to-use-include-random-with-g-on-a-mac), `#include <random>` is a C++11 header. You might want to check if your compiler supports it, and that the proper flags are set.

Otherwise, have you looked at `rand()`? It should be enough for basic random numbers.

Comment: This should be a comment, unfortunately to a question that has no answer thanks to its limited information.

Comment: Agreed, but I don't have the needed rep to comment right now. (Or at the time I wrote the answer, anyway.)

Comment: Thanks. I took a look at rand() it is perfect for what I need.

Comment: @Nelson Remember to check [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/) if you find something else messing up.

Comment: Use http://en.cppreference.com/w/ instead, it's a better reference.

Comment: In my opinion, [this](http://www.cplusplus.com) is better in most cases.

Comment: @BladeNelson In most cases? What makes you think that?

Comment: @0x499602D2 I agree that both of them have their "strong" points, the docs that I linked are TERRIBLE at giving nice examples. But at the same time, [this](en.cppreference.com/w) has other things suited for it. All in all, they are both good ways to help you code. :D