# C++ 11 auto feature

Tags: c++

i am new to c++ 11 . so i wore a small code using c++ 11 feature . but the compiler issues no type found error while using auto . my compiler is updated and i use osx mavericks
here's my code :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   vector<int> v(100);  
   for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
   {
      v[i]=i;
   }

   for(auto p=v.begin();p!=v.end();p++)
      cout<<*p<<'\t';
   cout<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You've not asked a question, just pasted some code. What problem are you seeing?

Comment: Which compiler are you using? And which command-line options did you pass to it?

Comment: http://ideone.com/r8wSkg

Comment: are you using the `-std=c++11` flag with your compiler?

Comment: the compiler gives the error that p does not have any type and i am using gcc 4.2 compiler

Comment: Since you're learning C++11, this would also be a good time to try out the new range based `for` loop. The second `for` can be rewritten as `for(auto const& i : v) std::cout << i << '\t';`. Also the `vector` can be initialized using [`std::iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota)

Comment: Or rewritten as `std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int i) { std::cout << i << "\t"; });`  Unless you are dead-set on figuring out what you can get away with with `auto`, there is no need for it at all to do what you are trying to do here.  You can even get away without a lambda:  `std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\t"));`

Comment: A stable release of 4.3 was out in 2008. The last update to 4.2 was in 2008. They're up to 4.8 now.

Comment: Use a newer compiler.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to pass the `-std=c++11` flag to your compiler or `-std=c++0x` depending on your compiler version.

If you're using `gcc 4.2`, chances are it doesn't have C++0x support yet.

See this [page](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html).

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480654/std-gnu0xoption-for-macos) might be of some use to you.

> GCC 4.2 is ancient, but Apple don't ship a newer version.
>
> You can either install a modern GCC from somewhere like Mac Ports
>   (which is probably simpler and quicker) or build it yourself following
>   the instructions at http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC

Comment: it says no input file

Comment: @user3006081 How do you compile? What did you type exactly?

Comment: @user3006081 I'm voting to close given that last comment. *What* says no input file *when*? If you refuse to give pertinent information unless we prod you for it repeatedly, it's very hard to be of assistance.

Comment: @user3006081 Did you mean `g++ -std=c++11 c11.cpp -o c11.o`???

Comment: Normal compilation: `g++ example.cpp -o example.o`. Compiling with C++11: `g++ example.cpp -o example.o -std=c++0x` or `g++ -std=c++0x example.cpp -o example.o` or `g++ example.cpp -std=c++0x -o example.o`. But there's no C++11 support for gcc 4.2, so it won't work: http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html